# Approximation error

Tags: matrices, approximation

Suppose matrix A has singular values 20, √π and 1/5, and that ˆb is an approximation to a “true” but unknown b, with approximation error at most 10−5. Let x and ˆx be the solutions of Ax = b and Axˆ = ˆb, respectively. How closely will ˆx approximate x?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Are those suspicious goo.gl links pointing to external resources or to stackexchange? I'm not clicking them.

Comment: @Stef To StackExchange. For instance, the first one points to [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement).

Comment: Thank you! I'm reading it now